# Memory consistency effects in ConcurrentMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

According to the [`ConcurrentMap` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html):

> Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a `ConcurrentMap` as a key or value *happen-before* actions subsequent to the access or removal of that object from the `ConcurrentMap` in another thread.

What is the meaning of above statement? And how does it work as the `get()` method in `ConcurrentHashMap` is not blocking (compared to `BlockingQueue` for example)?

Comment: I noticed that you didn't accept any answer yet. Please consider doing that at some point!

Answer (score 5):

The meaning is rather simple. Assume you have two pieces of code:

```
 a = new A();
 b = ...
 someConcurrentHashMap.put(b, whatever);
```

And then:

```
Whatever value = someConcurrentHashMap.get(b);
c = new C();
```

When `b` is the *same* object and these two pieces of code are executed by two **different threads**, then it is guaranteed that `a = new A()` *happens before* `c = new C()`.

For further reading on "happens before" - see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html).

For the implementation details I recommend you to study the source [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap) - that contains **tons** of (non-javadoc!) comments that explain the inner workings of this class.

Answer (score 2):

GhostCat already explained the meaning of happens-before. However, it might be worth noting the difference between this and "blocking".

In a blocking queue, a thread trying to poll from the queue will wait until something is available.

For something like a `ConcurrentHashMap`, this is not the case. A happens-before relationship simple means that everything you did before adding it to the map has still happened when the other thread accesses it. But it doesn't mean the other thread will wait for something with the given key to be available.

To give an example where this is important, consider two classes foo and bar. In the constructor of Foo, we add it to a list in Bar. Now we put this instance of Foo in the `ConcurrentHashMap` and access it in another thread. It is logical that everything we did to that instance of Foo has still happened. However, Java will also make sure that the instance of Foo has still been added to the list in Bar.